# How to calculate by rows in J

Tags: j

For example, there are two 164*90 matrixes and a function.

```
beta=: 4 : 0
a=. x cor y
b=. sd x
c=. sd y
a*b%c
)
```

I want to use each row of matrix 1  and each row of matrix 2 into the function. How can I do it at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
beta=: 4 : 0"1
a=. x cor y
b=. sd x
c=. sd y
a*b%c
)
```

The `"1` after the `0` in the definition above makes your verb rank 1 which means that it would take whatever matrices it is given a row at a time. An alternative would be to call your originally defined verb with rank `"1`

```
x beta"1 y
```